# How can I solve case-sensitive where like statement on json data in Laravel eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I use Laravel 5.6 and mysql database.

My Laravel eloquent query is like this:

```
Order::where('information->owner', 'like', '%'.$receipt.'%')->paginate(5);
```

Information field is a JSON type.

```
{"owner": "Chelsea"}
```

If `$receipt` is `Chel`, the query returns a result.

But if `$receipt` is `chel` or `CHEL`, the result is empty

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This might help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165447/is-it-possible-to-search-within-a-mysql-json-array-in-a-case-insensitive-manner

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try comparing the values after converting to lowercase or uppercase.

```
Order::whereRaw('LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(information, "$.owner")) like ?', ['"%' . strtolower($receipt) . '%"'])
     ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: There exist error : `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'information->owner) like %?%' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from orders where LOWER(information->owner) like %chel%)"`

Comment: change `like %?%` to `like "%?%"`

Comment: There is still exist error. The error like this : `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'information->owner) like "%?%"' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from orders where LOWER(information->owner) like "%chel%")`

Comment: It seems this does not work because field information is json data

Comment: Updated the answer. Try it now

Comment: It's the same. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715125/how-can-i-search-json-data-in-mysql/49715265?noredirect=1#comment86443783_49715265. I make a new question

Comment: It still does not work. If I modify your laravel eloquent to be like this : `Order::whereRaw('LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(information, "$.owner")) like "%'.strtolower($receipt).'%"')->paginate(5);`. It works

Comment: @SuccessMan Yeah, you are right. parameters inside quotes does not work. Updted the answer to reflect it

Answer (score 0):

If every owner begins with upper case first letter you can use `ucfirst` to uppercase the first letter of the string

```
$receipt = ucfirst($receipt);
Order::where('information->owner', 'like', '%'.$receipt.'%')->paginate(5);
```

Comment: It does not work. It seems that `information->owner` is also needed to change to lower case

Comment: Yep you've got a point there, I've updated my answer so you can use ucfirst()

Comment: Well it looks like you need to figure out you're data structure before you insert it into the database I guess - maybe have an owner name field (all lower case) + owner name label and only match on owner name field

Comment: Seems I don't use the way. I try this way : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46238718/laravelhow-to-use-lowercase-function-in-eloquent-query?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa. I implement to my case. But it does not work. Seems  because my case is where json. Maybe you can help me with the reference