# How can I search json data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have description field. The field is json

The contain of the description field is like this :

```
{
    "address": 
    {
        "street": "street 123", 
        "information": 
        {
            "province": "province 123",
            "regency": "regency 123", 
            "district": "district 123"
        }
    }, 
    "mobileNumber": "123"
}
```

I want to search province in the json data

I try like this :

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(description, "$.address.information.province")) LIKE "%prov%"
```

The result is empty

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: PROV is uppercase :-?

Comment: @Mahdi Parsa I update my question

Comment: Like shouldn’t be case sensitive. Have you tried to do “SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(...” to see what the function itself returns?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson If the field is no json, it's no case sensitive. But if the field is json, it's case sensitive. I had try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your JSON is not valid. There should not be commas after

```
"district": "district 123",
```

and

```
"mobileNumber": "123",
```

If you try with valid JSON, you will get the result you expect:

```
select json_extract('{ "address": { "street": "street 123",         "information": { "province": "province 123",  "regency": "regency 123",             "district": "district 123" } }, "mobileNumber": "123"}', '$.address.information.province')

"province 123"
```

I have created a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j9WLdvCawzDiPpAcrirGpb/0) which seems to work fine with your data:

```
create table x (id int, description json);
insert into x values(1, '{    "address":     {        "street": "street 123",         "information":         {            "province": "province 123",            "regency": "regency 123",             "district": "district 123"         }    },     "mobileNumber": "123"}');
select * from x where json_extract(description, '$.address.information.province') like '%prov%'
```

Output

```
id  description
1   {"address": {"street": "street 123", "information": {"regency": "regency 123", "district": "district 123", "province": "province 123"}}, "mobileNumber": "123"}
```

Comment: I had update my question. Look at that. It's the same. The result is empty

Comment: I'm not sure why that should be, I've tried a simple [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j9WLdvCawzDiPpAcrirGpb/0) and it works fine.

Comment: Your query is not use `lower`. Try to use `lower`. It does not work. I need to use `lower`

Comment: @SuccessMan, strange the example provided by Nick worked fine for me, with and without lower.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Whether you had change `province 123` to `Province 123` before try it?

Comment: @SuccessMan I've update the [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j9WLdvCawzDiPpAcrirGpb/2) to use lower and it still works fine.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The reason my query did not need lower was because the data and the thing being compared to were both in lower case. I have found the same thing that JSON data needs to be in the same case for LIKE to work (which is  weird...), try playing with the fiddle setting the LIKE string to `'%PROV%'` and you'll see it doesn't match (regardless of whether the lower is in place or not)

Answer (score -1):

three things:

1.when use mysql function 'JSON_EXTRACT',make suer the datatype is 'json';

2.there is something wrong with ur json data.deleted 2 commas.the right json should be like this:

```
{"address": {
    "street": "street 123",
    "information": {
        "province": "province 123",
        "regency": "regency 123",
        "district": "district 123"
    }
},
"mobileNumber": "123"}
```

3.it's case-sensitive. try use this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(description, "$.address.information.province") LIKE "%prov%"
```