# How to apply 'UPPER' to Eloquent query?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, php-7

How do I do this in Laravel's Eloquent?

I want my sql output to be this:

```
SELECT * FROM users UPPER(email) LIKE UPPER("%email%").
```

Here is the code I'm trying to modify:

```
$users = User::where('email', 'like', '%'.request('email').'%')->paginate(50);
```

I tried doing this but it didn't work:

```
$users = User::where('UPPER(email)', 'like', 'UPPER("%'.request('email').'%")')->paginate(50);
```

Comment: You could look at making `email` a [case insensitive](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) collation time on the database side. Then you don't need any special handling on the Eloquent side.

Comment: I'm connecting to an existing DB.

Comment: So what are the implications of an existing DB? Do you think it would affect any other application that uses this table if email was case insensitive? Which MySQL version?

Comment: I don't have control over the DB. The application connects to an existing DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `where Raw` maybe?

```php
User::whereRaw('UPPER(`email`) LIKE ? ',[trim(strtoupper($email)).'%'])->paginate(15);
```

This post looks like what you are trying to do.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46238839/13468924

Answer (score 0):

There's a reasonable chance your `email` isn't on a case sensitive collation in which case your existing unmodified code will match regardless of stored case (or email expression).

If you `email`  is case sensitive rather than forcing the case of the `email` and pattern, you can force the expression to be case insensitive like:

```
select * from users where email LIKE '%user%' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8280039d744c579d11bea90070a65638)

note: available collations is dependent on the major version of mysql. [show collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-collation.html) will list them however.

note: sorry, I don't know the Eloquent syntax for this